# Is it all right to end this sentence with a question mark?

Tags: punctuation, questions

I am writing a story, and one sentence has been bugging me.

> What was going on with that, I wondered?

It's an interior thought, and so I don't use quotations. If it were dialogue, I would put the question mark after "that," but it's not. It feels more natural that way I have it up there, but is it incorrect? Maybe these are better options:

> What was going on with that, I wondered.

OR

> What was going on with that? I wondered.

Thank you!

Comment: You end a sentence with a question mark if it should be spoken with a rising tone at the end, indicative of a question.  It would be omitted if the "question" is rhetorical (and hence would not be spoken with the shift in tone that indicates a question).

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not an interrogative sentence as the subject is "I" and the main verb is "wondered". "What was going on with that" is an object of the verb to "wonder". It is a declarative sentence which is inverted for emphasis from the following sentence:

> I wondered what was going on with that.

It would be better to use quotation marks (double quotes in American English and single quotes in British English) if you want to place a question mark as follows:

> "What was going on with that?" I wondered.

Regarding the punctuation in direct speech, you can visit the [link](http://www.grammaring.com/punctuation-in-direct-speech) and see how it works.

Comment: What would you suggest if I don't want to use quotation marks?

Comment: @Mik I think it would be better to use your second example.